# What is a word for being obviously humorous?

Tags: single-word-requests

So I'm trying to write a piece of dialogue and I can't remember this word for the life of me and Google isn't helping. I know it's similar to sarcasm in usage but not quite.

The characters are in a cave. That's the obvious bit.

> "Yeah," he said as he pushed himself off the ground. "Where are we?"
>
> "A cave," He said ____

What word should I use. Please help.

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: I would go with "flatly" but I know that's not what you're looking for

Comment: Maybe deadpan could work here?

Comment: I guess you mean "being humorous by stating the obvious" rather than "not hiding the fact you are joking"?

Comment: Adverbs on dialogue tags are generally frowned up, but I might use "drily" here. (But be careful you don't turn into Tom Swift: "'A cave', he said hollowly." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Swifty)

Comment: @JustFriendly: you commented on the other answer that "I think drily was what I was looking for". I'm glad our site has helped you out! Note also that you can also "tick" [my answer below](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/494298/167396) if you feel inclined, to indicate to future readers that this is indeed your preferred solution. I get a small bonus for my effort, you get a small bonus for accepting an answer, and the site gets a bonus for all the parts working harmoniously! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The word to express how humour might be delivered in a deadpan or ironic manner is:

> **[drily](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/drily)** (also *dryly*)
>   ADVERB
>
> 1. In a matter-of-fact or ironically humorous way.
>      *" 'How very observant', he said drily"*
>      *" 'Fifty songs,' I mused. 'Five thousand dollars worth of digital matter,' I added to myself dryly."*
>      *" 'We call it the belly of the beast,' she dryly remarks."*
>
> [Source: Oxford Living Dictionaries]

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drily) doesn't specifically define the adverb, but gives the following definition for the adjective and notes "*dryly* also *drily* adverb":

> 14. marked by matter-of-fact, ironic, or terse manner of expression
>       *a dry wit*
>       *has a very dry sense of humor*

The key in using *drily* is that there is an element of humour or irony inherent in the statement but the delivery itself gives no indication of humour or other emotion.

Answer (score 0):

Making a joke that is obvious, and perhaps sometimes inappropriate, is to be **facetious**:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1** : joking or jesting often inappropriately : WAGGISH
>   // just being *facetious*
>   **2** : meant to be humorous or funny : not serious
>   // a *facetious* remark

In your example, you would use its adverb form.

The characters are obviously in a cave, so:

> "A cave," he said *facetiously*.

Comment: Thank you guys. I think drily was what I was looking for. But if you have anothe suggestion it would definitly help